# ARC enabled in Cocos2d Box2d project?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, box2d, box2d-iphone

I was wondering if you can enable ARC in a Box2d project without any issues, or if it is simpler and easier to not use ARC with Box2d projects?

Comment: You can [disable ARC on per-file basis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: Regarding box2D, since it's in C++, there is no ARC or non-ARC for it. ARC doesn't affect it at all. For cocos2d in general I suggest you reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532557/does-cocos2d-support-arc

Answer (score 1):

Enable ARC, Box2D is not affected by ARC and it's not wise to start any new project without ARC.

The only thing you need to consider is to `__bridge` cast from and to from Box2D's void* userData properties. Plenty of examples abound, and really simple.

Comment: LearnCocos2D thanks that helps but could you post and example of the _bridge cast? Would greatly appreciate it:)